# FuncAnimation does not work until I plot data AFTER calling the animation function

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt5, matplotlib-animation

I'm trying to understand what's going on here. FuncAnimation does not start working unless I plot data AFTER initialising the animation. I've tried to simplify the problem here.

So in this example, if I press plot first, then press start, the animation does not work. But if I press plot again, it starts working. Why is this?

```
import sys
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout

class GraphObject:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.fig = Figure()
        self.axis = self.fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        self.axis.axes.set(xlim=(0,200), ylim=(0,1))
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
        
    def plotData(self, data, clear=True):
        if clear:
            self.axis.clear()
        self.axis.plot(data)
        self.canvas.draw()
        
    def lineTracker(self, x=None):
        while len(self.axis.lines) > 1:
            self.axis.lines[-1].remove()
        self.axis.axvline(x)
        
class GraphModel:
    
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.graph = GraphObject()
        self.data = data

    def plotData(self):
        self.graph.plotData(self.data)
    
    def initAnimation(self):
        self.animation = animation.FuncAnimation(self.graph.fig, self.graph.lineTracker, interval=1000/30,
                                        repeat=True)
        
class GraphViewer(QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        data = list(range(200))
        self.graph = GraphModel(data)
        self.initUI()
        self.connectSignals()
        
    def initUI(self):
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.start = QPushButton('start')
        self.plot = QPushButton('plot')
        layout.addWidget(self.graph.graph.canvas)
        layout.addWidget(self.start)
        layout.addWidget(self.plot)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        
    def connectSignals(self):
        self.start.clicked.connect(self.graph.initAnimation)
        self.plot.clicked.connect(self.graph.plotData)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ui = GraphViewer()
ui.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: no idea but if you add self.graph.plotData(self.data) underneath def initAnimation(self): before self.animation .... and you press start twice you get the animation

Comment: in any case you need to call the plot first to get the diagonal then trackliner empties ti with the moving lines